# Product is not showing when I enter SKU in the URL bar (www.mysite.com/sku)

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, sku

I have enabled the `Amasty_ElasticSearch` module, when I put SKU in the site URL, It shows an error 404 message. Like this : ([www.mysite.com/sku](http://www.mysite.com/sku)).

But I have another Site where It brings me the product view page. That Site has MySql search enabled.

I want the same functionality with the `Amasty_ElasticSearch` module.

Please Help.

Comment: Please verify your site Amasty_ElasticSearch module's configurations with your another site. Maybe you have misconfigured it on your site or you have missed something in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, while searching for a product through catalog search, Magento uses all attributes for which the value of **`Use in Search`** is set to **`Yes`**.

Set the value of **`Use in Search`** to **`Yes`** for SKU.

After that Reindex and check again.